# Linux use sed command to change string from start and end position for all records in a file

Tags: linux, sed

Working with a file in Linux and need to manipulate a file to insert a string for a specified start and end position.  I'm just learning how to use scripting language, and I have looked for through several sed examples, but nothing that does what I need.  So the goal I have is to replace every row in a file with the same string starting at position 20 thru position 33 inclusive.  Each record is about 2000 characters long.  Replace the 14 character span with a string that is only 8 characters.  "A0000CDD"

So start records of

`2017-04-01 01:13:20<11102233HRDS>30511version=1.0.....
 2017-04-01 01:13:20<11102234HRDS>30511version=1.0.....
 2017-04-01 01:13:20<11102235HRDS>30511version=1.0.....
 2017-04-01 01:13:20<11102236HRDS>30511version=1.0.....`

should end as

`2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
 2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
 2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
 2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....`

All the sed examples seem to want to replace a pattern where I just need to replace the same positions with the same string.

As a note, I was able to do this by inputting each record of the file and manipulating each record and output to another file.  The problem is that the files will contain a few million records, and the processing takes too long.

Appreciate the help

MG

Comment: Could the pattern be a string that starts with `<` and ends with `>`?

Comment: The <  >  pattern shows up in several places on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/(.{19}).{14}(.*)/\1A0000CDD\2/' file
```

Output:

```
2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** alternative:

```
awk -F" |=" '{FS=OFS;gsub(/<.{12}>/,"A0000CDD",$2)} 1' file
```

The output:

```
2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version 1.0.....
2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
2017-04-01 01:13:20A0000CDD30511version=1.0.....
```